# why my app is crashing on map

Tags: android, android-support-library

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dub.app.bridgewaterstate/com.dub.app.bridgewaterstate.ui.CoursesMapScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4127)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2187)
       at com.dub.app.bridgewaterstate.ui.CoursesMapScreen.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4127)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2187)
       at com.dub.app.bridgewaterstate.ui.CoursesMapScreen.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4127)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
       at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:763)
       at aby.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:74)
       at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
       at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source)
       at xu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.getMap(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.getState(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zztU(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zztU(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2187)
       at com.dub.app.bridgewaterstate.ui.CoursesMapScreen.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4127)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

My Layout file is :

```
  <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <include android:id="@+id/courses_map_header_id"
        layout="@layout/widget_ic_action_header" /> 
       <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  android:id="@+id/courses_map_id" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/courses_map_header_id"
        android:clickable="true"/> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Serious? Add more details.

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/courses_map_header_id"
        layout="@layout/widget_ic_action_header" />


 <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:id="@+id/courses_map_id"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/courses_map_header_id"
        android:clickable="true"/>    

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Can you post the code of your layout file? Its clearly showing that you are using custom map class in your code and you are giving incorrect class name in your file. Besides giving your custom map class name in your layout file.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following things exists in your manifest file:

```
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="your value" />
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And set your xml layout to display map as below:

```
 <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class
```

Check this line in your xml file, you probably have a typo.

Comment: what should be there?

Comment: RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` ; ` remove the semicolon

Comment: there is no semicolon in xml file

Comment: ah, I knew it was not a good idea to answer this question, I should have listened my intuition